# Problem in Iterate through list and return the value

Tags: c#

I have a list which has accounts in it and I am trying to make a function which takes in the parameter name and Iterate through the list and return the first account which has the same name as the passed in the name parameter.

If there is an account with the matching name then return the bank else return null.

```
public class Account {

     // Defining some private variables...
     private decimal _balance;
     private string _name;

     public string Name{
         get { return _name; }
     }

     public Account(string name, decimal startingBalance){
         _name = name;
         _balance = startingBalance;
     }
}

public class Bank {

      private static List<Account> _accounts = new List<Account>();

      public Bank(){ }

      public void AddAccount(Account account){
            _accounts.Add(account);
      }

      // method to check if an account exist in list of accounts.. 
      public Account GetAccount(string name){
            Account account;
            for (int i = 0; i < _accounts.Count; i++){
                 if (name == _accounts[i].Name){
                     account = _accounts[i];
                     return account;
                 }
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(account)))
            {
                 return null;
            }    
      } 
}
```

This is what I thought but it is showing error. 
1. Not all code paths return the value.
2. use of unassigned local variable 'account'.

Any help in making GetAccount code, please?

Comment: You don't need last `String.IsNullOrEmpty` verification.

Comment: better to do  --> `_accounts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == name);`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to check the account variable after the loop if the program reaches there, it can't find the account certainly. This solves the "Not all code paths return the value" issue too. Also, you can return the object without using another variable (account).

```
public Account GetAccount(string name){

    for (int i = 0; i < _accounts.Count; i++){
        if (name == _accounts[i].Name){
            return _accounts[i];
        }
    }

    return null;

}
```

By the way, it's better to use LINQ do such works (as @Aomine mentioned):

```
public Account GetAccount(string name){
    return _accounts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == name);
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, that was what I was missing was thinking wrong. You are right, just needed to add return null at the end. And yes I corrected that extra variable mistake too. Works perfectly now. Thanks a lot all.

Answer (score 0):

The messages you have are not errors. They are warnings.
You could return `account` in your `GetAccount` function.

```
public Account GetAccount(string name){
        Account account = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < _accounts.Count; i++){
             if (name == _accounts[i].Name){
                 account = _accounts[i];
                 return account;
             }
        }
        return account; 
  }
```